# How to get "Application ID" from Amazon Pinpoint through postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to get application ID for sending a message from AWS Pinpoint through Postman, But I am unable to get the Application ID.

`/v1/apps/application-id/messages`

This is the application ID That I want. Can you guys help me to get that. I need to implement AWS pinpoint Message to my PHP Project.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an existing Amazon Pinpoint application, you can retrieve the Pinpoint Project-ID or application-ID using the following options :

**1)** Amazon Pinpoint Console :

[image]

or

[image]

**2)** Amazon Pinpoint CLI **"get-apps"** command as shown below:-

[image]

**3)** Amazon Pinpoint REST API using tools like :

**a) Postman:** Using this [Amazon Pinpoint tutorial for POSTMAN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/tutorials-using-postman-configuration.html), you can setup Postman and use it to perform Amazon Pinpoint actions including retrieval Pinpoint application ID or project ID by calling the **"GetApps"** or **"GetApp"** API.

**b) [awscurl:](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl)** A sample illustration of how to use awscurl to retrieve Pinpoint Application ID or project ID is given below :

```
$ awscurl -H "Content-type: application/json" --service mobiletargeting https://pinpoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/apps/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can get you started.
Summary: You are referring to the *application-id* that is the PATH component of the POST URL for sending a direct message from Pinpoint to a recipient, which is discussed here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/rest-api-messages.html
The *application-id* identifies the app instance that will receive the message from Pinpoint.

Solution: I don´t know the device or execution context of your project.
However, according to the Pinpoint documentation, the Amazon Pinpoint management console or the Amazon Pinpoint REST API enable you to send push notifications to a recipient, **regardless** of the recipient´s device type or platform (see "Using Amazon Pinpoint to send push notifications" at the following URL: https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/push-notification-services/).

Using the Pinpoint REST API, you get the *application-id* from Pinpoint when you create an app of your project. See the HTTP POST method of the *apps* resource page here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/rest-api-apps.html
The POST method creates an app, and its ApplicationResponse schema contains the *id* attribute that is "The unique ID for the application."
Hope this helps.